# LWC record-edit-form wont work with rich text area field

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-recordeditform

I am trying to update a rich text area field inside record-edit-form in lwc but it wont update once clicked inside the rich-text-area field placeholder.

[image]

Scenario is: This UI is for an Edit Page. On Field 3 picklist change, I am updating the selected row Id as the id of matching row for Field 1 and Field 3 picklist option.

if I dont click on the Rich-text-area field, all the fields are updated accordingly.
but once clicked on the Rich-text-area-field and then if I change the picklist value, Field 1 and Field 2 updates fine but the rich-text-area-field will not update and gets stuck

I've already see few blogs which were sort of having the same issue with the rich-text-area field but havent found a solution or reasoning why it wont work.

HTML part---

```
<lightning-record-edit-form 
                        record-id = {selectedRowId}
                        object-api-name = "Object__c" 
                        onerror = {handleError}
                        onsuccess = {handleSuccess}>
                        <div class="slds-grid slds-wrap cls">  
                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_8-of-12"> 
                             
                                <div class="sslds-col slds-size_4-of-12">
                                    <h3 class="cls-nmv-ppw"> Field 3</h3>
                                    <lightning-input-field field-name="Field3__c" variant="label-hidden" onchange={handleChangefield3} ></lightning-input-field>
                                </div></div>
                                <div class="cls-inptfld">
                                    <lightning-input-field class="harrier-nmv-type" field-name="Rich-Text-Area-Field" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>
                                </div>
                            
                           </div>

                            <div class="slds-col slds-size_12-of-12">
                                <div class="class-button-right">

                                    <lightning-button class="slds-m-left_xx-small hn-cancel"
                                        variant="brand"
                                        type="cancel"
                                        name="cancel"
                                        label="Cancel"
                                        onclick={handleCancel}>
                                    </lightning-button>

                                    <lightning-button
                                        class=" slds-m-left_xx-small hn-save"
                                        variant="brand"
                                        type="submit"
                                        name="update"
                                        label="Update"
                                        disabled = {buttonTrue}>
                                    </lightning-button>
                                
                                </div>
                            </div> 
                    
                        
                    </lightning-record-edit-form>
```

JS PART

```
handleChangefield3(event) {
    
    let valueOffield3 = event.target.value;
    this.field3 = valueOffield3 === this.defaultfield3Dropdown ? '' : valueOffield3;
    
    if(this.field3 == '') {
        this.buttonTrue = true;
    }
    
    else if(this.field3 != '') {
        this.buttonTrue = false;
        for(let value in this.accountArray) {
            this.accountArray[value].value.forEach(row => {

                if(row.Field3__c == this.field3 
                    && row.Field2__c == this.field2
                    && row.Account__c == this.account) {
                        
                        this.matchFound = true;
                        this.buttonTrue = false;
                        this.selectedRowId = row.Id;
                } 
            });
            if(this.matchFound == true) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if(this.matchFound == false) {

            this.dispatchEvent(
                new ShowToastEvent({
                    title: 'Warning!',
                    message: ' record does not exist!',
                    variant: 'warning'
                }),
            ); 
            this.buttonTrue = true;
        }
        this.matchFound = false;
    }
}
```

onChange of Field 3, I am looping through an array of objects and finding the match for Field1 and Field3, if found I am replacing the selected row Id, so all values will update for the match found.

I am looking for this standard thing to work only as I know the other option might be with the custom code only.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you

NOTE: I tried changing the rich text area field to just text type and it gets updated fine, but doesnt work with rich-text-area.

Comment: Can you post at least some code. What do you mean by `updating`? normally LWC record-edit-form does not update the data for you, you are meant to use `updateRecord()` for it

Comment: @zaitsman just updated some code for the onChange update part. "this.selectedRowId = row.Id;" should update my Rich-text-area field value as well
Thank you

Comment: There is not enough, please add your layout, as it is not clear what event you are actually handling.

Comment: @zaitsman Code updated.
handleChangefield3 is the onChange event in which I want to update the Rich-text-area field as well

Comment: As your code clearly shows, you never wired `onChange` of `<lightning-input-field class="harrier-nmv-type" field-name="Rich-Text-Area-Field" variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input-field>`

Comment: @zaitsman but I need the rich-text-area-field to be changed/updated on onChange of field3.    Also how come it works then when I change it to just text type